# model (3ds) stats & snapshot in linux

Tags: browser, models, 3ds

I want to write an app that takes in a model filename via cmd line, create a list of stats (poly count, scaling, as much as possible or maybe the stats that i would like) and to load the model with its textures (with anything else) and draw it from multiple position to save the images as pngs.

How would i do this? are there utils i can use to extract data from models? how about drawing the models? my server does not have a desktop or video card, would no video HW be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use http://www.lib3ds.org/ for reading the data, IIRC it also comes with a sample program that you could base your code on.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the 3DS specifications at [wotsit.org](http://www.wotsit.org/list.asp?fc=2). AFAIK, there are no official specs. Another possibility would be to look for open source 3DS libraries/tools and use them.